# opening email client with attachment

Tags: vb.net, email

I,m looking a way to open the default email client that has the computer installed (Outlook or groupwise) and attach a file. The user will be entering the other information in the email client.

Tried:

```
Dim SendFrom As MailAddress = New MailAddress("test@email.com")
Dim SendTo As MailAddress = New MailAddress("test@email.com") 
Dim MyMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage(SendFrom, SendTo) 
MyMessage.Subject = "Hola" 
MyMessage.Body = "Body:" 
'Dim attachFile As New Attachment("C:\test.txt") 
'MyMessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile) 
Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient("yahoo.com") 
emailClient.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue 
emailClient.Send(MyMessage) 
TextBox1.Text = "Message Sent"
```

Comment: You need to prove that you have tried something, and the community will try to help. SO won't do your work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I try this, but it do not support attachment   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & "j" & "?Subject=" & "jola" & "&Body=" & "txtBody" & "&Attach=" & "c:\test.txt")

Comment: Also This, but  I want to allow the user to use it email client: Dim SendFrom As MailAddress = New MailAddress("test@email.com")
        Dim SendTo As MailAddress = New MailAddress("test@email.com")


        Dim MyMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage(SendFrom, SendTo)


        MyMessage.Subject = "Hola"
        MyMessage.Body = "Body:"

'Dim attachFile As New Attachment("C:\test.txt")
'MyMessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile)
Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient("yahoo.com")
        emailClient.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue
        emailClient.Send(MyMessage)
TextBox1.Text = "Message Sent"

Comment: I moved your code to your question body. You can always edit your post with what you have tried

Comment: Erm, this has just been edited to br VB.Net only. My answer was just for VB6.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is using MAPI

This is some code for VB6:

```
Public Function MailtoWithAttachment(ByVal Recipient As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Body As String, ByVal Attachment As String) As Boolean
Dim Message As MAPIMessage
Dim RecipientA() As Byte
Dim Recipients(0) As MapiRecip
Dim AttachmentA() As Byte
Dim Attachments(0) As MapiFile
Dim SubjectA() As Byte
Dim BodyA() As Byte

Dim Result As Long

  'Set the recipient
  RecipientA = StrConv(Recipient & vbNullChar, vbFromUnicode)
  Recipients(0).lpName = VarPtr(RecipientA(0))
  Recipients(0).RecipClass = MAPI_TO
  Message.RecipCount = 1
  Message.lpRecips = VarPtr(Recipients(0))

  'Add the attachment
  AttachmentA = StrConv(Attachment & vbNullChar, vbFromUnicode)
  Attachments(0).lpPathName = VarPtr(AttachmentA(0))
  Attachments(0).Position = -1
  Message.FileCount = 1
  Message.lpFiles = VarPtr(Attachments(0))

  'Subject
  SubjectA = StrConv(Subject & vbNullChar, vbFromUnicode)
  Message.lpSubject = VarPtr(SubjectA(0))

  'And body
  BodyA = StrConv(Body & vbNullChar, vbFromUnicode)
  Message.lpNoteText = VarPtr(BodyA(0))

  'Try and send the email
  Result = MAPISendMail(0, 0, ByVal VarPtr(Message), MAPI_DIALOG, 0&)
  'Return false if there was a problem (ignoring canel)
  MailtoWithAttachment = Result = 0 Or Result = 1
End Function
```

This uses the declarations from [MAPI32.bas](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163216) and makes heavy use of unicode to ANSI conversion and pointers in structures.

Note that not all mail clients support this, for which the only solution is to use a custom interface for each.

Comment: I was able to make the code work in one computer, but when I install it in other computer I recieve the following error: MAPISendMail failed! General MAPI failure [2], when it try to open my client. What could cause this problem?

Comment: @user1725253 I don't. Unsupported mail client? Or something mistranslated to VB.Net?

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what development environment you working with. See if you can construct a .EML file. And start a new process to load the file. This works as long as your email client is associated with the .EML extension.

Here you can find an example for the .NET environment.

[Open default mail client along with a attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment/25586282#25586282)